# Elastic Beanstalk and Laravel queues

Tags: laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-queue

I'm implementig Laravel queues via database driver, and when I start the process for listening the jobs, another process is also started.
So basically I'm doing php artisan queue:listen and the process that is automatically started is php artisan queue:work.

[image]
so basically the second process here is generated automatically, also the thing is that it doesnt point to the folder where it should be

Comment: what is the problem? are you getting any errors?

Comment: there is no error in there, I just want to know why is it starting automatically, and since it is already started it is not pointing to the folder where it should start processing jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The listener:**

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

starts a long-running process that will "run" (process) new jobs as they are pushed onto the queue. See [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#running-the-queue-listener).

**The processer:**

```
php artisan queue:work
```

Will process new jobs as they are pushed onto the queue. See [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#running-the-queue-worker).

So basically `queue:listen` runs `queue:work` as and when new jobs are pushed.

**P.S**: You need not worry about this but its good to know how it works. You can dig into [the code](https://github.com/illuminate/queue) if you need more information.

Comment: thank you very much, but is there any problem since the queue:work is executed in a different folder from the project, so I guess that should'nt work

Comment: @RinorDreshaj The parent process of the queue:work is queue:listen in this case. So it will just work.